# How to navigate to PHP keywords source code in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

In my PhpStorm I write a code snippet:

```
final class Demo{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

But how can I navigate to keywords source code? such as `final`,  `class`, `public`.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: The implementation of such keywords is written in C and I'm positively sure that there isn't a single spot in the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src) that defines them because they do nothing by themselves—freely speaking, they're like hints for the language parser.

Answer (score 2):

Those keywords are the so-called **reserved keywords** which are built into PHP language and the IDE's interpreter, there is NOT ANY WAY to follow them because you can not create or change them, for a complete list visit:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Or even see:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but they're not, really: they are language constructs. You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to confusion.
>
> As of PHP 7.0.0 these keywords are allowed as property, constant, and method names of classes, interfaces and traits, except that class may not be used as constant name.

Answer (score 2):

PHPStorm doesn’t support it, nor any other IDE (those I know) support it. You can navigate to builtin functions, classes but not to language [keywords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) / language constructs.